# React hooks object update gets strange behaviour on Safari browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-hooks

React hooks object update gets strange behaviour on Safari browser(only on Safari browser)

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
  show_welcome: true,
  show_inline: false,
  restriction: false,
  request_dp: false,
  prevent_rtl: false,
  lang: "ta"
});
```

**setState**

```
const handleToggle = ({ target }) => {
  setState(s => ({ ...s, [target.name]: !s[target.name] }));
};
```

Is there anything break the order of object for Safari browser

[image: React hooks object update gets strange behaviour on Safari browser]

[image: Edit infallible-keldysh-uolgt]

Comment: Did you check the same logic without the CSS which comes from `react-bootstrap`? Why do you think its a "react-hooks" problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: Have you tried adding a `key={key}` on the form inputs?

Comment: You are placing the updated property at the end of the object on each update. Hence the item that you interact with is being rendered at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because it's re-rendering the array that you are using for the keys and the keys aren't in the same order as they were in the first render. You can see this by adding a `console.log(state)` just before the first return. Safari is more strict in this than Chrome or Firefox.

You can fix this by sorting the array before using it to render.

You can also fix this by changing your toggle function to something like this:

```
const handleToggle = ({ target }) => {
    const tempState = { ...state };
    tempState[target.name] = !tempState[target.name];
    setState(tempState);
  };
```

Comment: OP is not using an array, he's using an object.

Comment: `Object.keys(state).map(...)` returns an array. =)